# What is the best approach to displaying drawings on different-sized Paper JS views?

Tags: paperjs

**Context**

I'm using Paper JS to build a multi-player drawing game. At any given point, a single user will be drawing to his/her canvas, and the data will get sent to the server to be broadcast to other users. Each user's canvas may be of variable size, and it resizes as the window resizes while maintaining the same aspect ratio.

The goal is for each user to have a scaled representation of the drawing (i.e. everything fits inside the different sized canvases and the content doesn't get distorted). This should be the case if a drawing transfers from a larger canvas to a smaller canvas, and vice-versa. The project supports a drawing tool as well as an eraser tool.

**Problem**

Approach 1 below scales the drawings the way I want, but there is substantial lag. Approach 2 deals with the lag, but doesn't scale the drawings the way I want.

My understanding is that SVGs will scale nicely whether they are scaled-up or scaled-down. But rasters are pixel-based and will become "blurry" when scaled-up. When I test approach 2, a drawing from a smaller canvas gets blurred on a larger canvas. The result is the same whether I use export/importJSON or export/importSVG. Is there a way to get both good performance and scaled-drawings? See below for example implementations of the tools.

**Approach 1: Paths + Symbols:**

- Every path/symbol placement is kept in the active layer.
- The eraser tool draws a white rectangle (defined as a symbol) to
  mimic an "erasing" effect.
- This works fine as a demo, but will start to lag very quickly as the
  number of items in the active layer increases. The eraser tool in
  particular will not function smoothly.
- [Relevant sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.12.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)

**Approach 2: Rasterization:**

- After a path is drawn or a symbol is placed, the active layer is
  rasterized and its children are removed.
- This seems to work quite well on a single canvas, and the eraser
  doesn't lag like in the first approach. There are only 2 items in the
  active layer after each rasterization.
- When a drawing from a client with a smaller canvas is exported (using exportJSON or exportSVG) to a client with a larger canvas, the result is "blurry".
- The above also happens when a drawing is made and then the canvas is re-sized to be larger.
- [Relevant sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.12.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)

Comment: I don't know anything about paper JS but in general I would try to solve this by rasterizing a to a large image (as large as you expect the canvas to ever be), allowing it to be imported into any size canvas only be scaling down. If paper JS doesn't allow this, you could try raw JavaScript canvas.

Answer (score 0):

You could send your objects as SVG and rasterize them once received.